# Unable to change theme that applies to view

Tags: 7, views, theming

In a drupal page view under `advanced=>Theme:Information=>Change Theme`, I'm able to select a theme from the dropdown. Custom templates I've created go bold as expected. But when I save the view and check the theme information, it always reverts to the site default theme. I've tried this with a custom theme I created and a view themes that came with my installation.

Comment: Is your custom theme set as default theme under yoursite/admin/appearance/settings?

Comment: No, the custom theme was created specifically with this view in mind.

Comment: The theme selector under the advanced view section is not for selecting a theme that should be displayed, it's only for informational purposes afaik.

Comment: I see. Any idea how to override the default theme just for that page?

Comment: I recommend this little tutorial for a start: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-templates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a different theme for a specific page, try the [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module. It allows you to define rules for automatically selecting a theme. You can create a rule to switch theme for a particular path, which is probably the one you want. Another useful one is to select the theme based on the user's role. For example you can test theme modifications on a production site by showing one theme for anonymous users and your work-in-progress theme for the administrator role